# How to enable/disable proxy

Tags: 14.04

I am facing some issues with loading some specific web pages, the web pages does not load at all. Some of them are: www.w3schools.com, edx.org/login, omappedia.org & many more are there, I cannot list all of them. Please help me out I'm very new to Ubuntu, Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open "Network" and if you want to disable proxy select "None" after Method label and click Apply system wide button to save changes.

[image]

Comment: proxy in my system is already disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type `ifconfig`.

Check if proxies are needed. Then open "Network" and change it manually to the needed proxy.